# What Effect Will Installing A Custom Launcher Have On MIUI V.5?

Tags: launcher, miui

A friend installed the custom rom MIUI V.5, and is finding it a bit different to stock jelly bean. I told him to give it time to adjust, as i'm sure "its not that different".

Rather than disposing of MIUI altogether, he says he is thinking of installing a custom launcher eg Nova launcher.

He therefore wishes to know what effect (if any) will installing Nova launcher have on MIUI, and will it bring the stock Jelly Bean "experience" back or not ?

**Edit:**

**What he trying to say is:
By combining Nova launcher with MIUI, will the experience/functionality of doing so be similar to using Nova launcher with stock jelly bean, thereby making this transition to MIUI less unfamiliar & more user friendly ?**

Comment: If you do not like miui and rather want stock jellybean then why not switch back. I don't see the point of this question.

Answer (score 3):

First, launchers are apps like all other apps you can install. Which means: per se, there should be no problems -- but they of course might have bugs and, in rare cases, side effects. Again, this is not limited to launchers. So far for the "generic info".

Now specifically for the launcher: After having installed a launcher (Nova should be fine, Apex might be another choice close to Nova), when he presses the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to switch to the home screen, he will be asked which launcher to chose. So still he's got the choice to use the MIUI launcher or his "custom one". On every press of the <kbd>Home</kbd> button. Until he decides to always use one of the two, and marks the check button to remember his choice ("always use..."). *Now* on <kbd>Home</kbd> key press, it's always that launcher being started.

If at a later time he wants to switch back: still no problem. The "decision popup" will come again if one of the following conditions are met:

- he installed another launcher
- one of the installed launchers receives an update
- more than 2 launchers were installed, and the current default launcher is uninstalled
- in *Settings→Applications*, the settings of the current default launcher are opened, and the "clear defaults" button is pushed
- some "default apps" manager was used to trigger it

So in short: I'd expect no trouble. Some special features of the MIUI launcher might not be available in other launchers, some specific MIUI widgets (specifically built for the MIUI launcher) might not work with the other launcher -- but if he wants, he can always return/swtich or even revert his changes.

Comment: By adding Nova, this will have very little impact on the way he uses MIUI ?

Comment: As written: just adding it will have the effect he will be asked which launcher to use when pressing the "Home" button. But once he starts liking *Nova* more, he of course might use MIUI differently :) No worries. He can always uninstall *Nova* if he doesn't like the results.

Comment: So having Nova could potentially make using MIUI different, than not having it installed....if i'm making sense...in other words by having Nova on MIUI, would therefore be similar to having Nova on Stock Jelly Bean in terms of user experience?

Comment: I'd say so. Just give it a try and see for yourself. As I wrote, no damage to be expected -- and if you don't like it, simply uninstall it again. After all, it's an app -- and you do use apps on MIUI, don't you? ;)

Comment: Thats what i tried to say...by putting Nova on MIUI, it would make the phone similar in functionality to putting Nova on Stock JB, and therefore make MIUI less different and more friendly so to speak :)......Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well,

You will lose home launcher. That's it. Every other MIUI feature will be intact :-)

Comment: You won't lose it, it'll still be there. Just something else will be in use.

Comment: @Malfist I meant the same.. You will loose = you will be using other one :P